# unable to get the complete list of file matching the regular expression in shell script

Tags: shell

I have a directory with list of files `abc_1.txt abc_2.txt`.
I am have to parse the file name and do some processing over the file

```
  #shellscript /tmp/log*
  file_list=`ls $1`
  for file_name in $file_list
  do
     # need to do some processing over the file name
     echo $file_name
  done
```

the script is not giving the proper output i.e script is not giving  matching wildcard file name for the `ls` cmd.
the usage of the above script is `shellscript /tmp/log*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash expands `shellscript /tmp/log/abc*` to a list of files names as input to your script. `ls` is not needed. Just iterate over the input. Try it like this

```
for f in $*
do
 echo "Processing $f"
 # do something on $f
done
```

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-loop-over-file/ even gives you some more examples.

Comment: After `mkdir /tmp/log20150512; touch /tmp/log20150512/abc_1.txt` and calling `shellscript /tmp/log*` the dir and not the file is shown.

Comment: @Walter A, thanks for the hint. Edited my answer. Finally it is on you which flavour you use.

Answer (score 1):

When you want filenames without the dir you can use

```
if [ ! -d "$*" ]; then
        echo "Usage: $0 dirname"
        exit 1
fi
cd "$*"
find . -type f | cut -c3- | while read file_name; do
        echo "Found ${file_name}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the wildcard character "*" since it matches all the files in the given path. Removing it will just pass the directory path and your script will print each file

Comment: I think the dir is /tmp/log_something_like_20150512 and inside that dir the files like abc_1.txt